# SQL to LINQ conversion with inner join and where filters on different tables

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

What will the following query:

```
select (UserRoles.RoleID, UserRoles.UserID) from UserRoles  
    inner Join Roles on Roles.RolesID = UserRoles.RoleID 
    where Roles.RoleName = 'Seller' AND UserRoles.UserID =1
```

look like in Entity framework?

I tried this:

```
var check = from a in UserRole 
            join b in Role 
            on a.RoleID equals b.RoleID
            select new{RoleName ="seller"};
```

but it's wrong, could someone please guide me?

Answer (score 1):

The verbatim conversion of the query (after removing the parents in `SELECT`)

```
select UserRoles.RoleID, UserRoles.UserID
from UserRoles  
inner Join Roles on Roles.RolesID = UserRoles.RoleID 
where Roles.RoleName = 'Seller' AND UserRoles.UserID =1;
```

Would be the following in query syntax, against your `DbContext` called `context` (and I've assumed the default plural naming convention of DbSets:)

```
var result = from a in context.UserRoles
             join b in context.Roles
             on a.RoleID equals b.RoleID
             where b.RoleName == "Seller" && a.UserId == 1
             select new {b.RoleID, a.UserID};
```

Where we join the tables and project out the two columns you wanted.

However, if you've defined the navigation property `UserRole.Role` in your EF Model, explicit joining isn't required, and much simpler would be (I've switched to lambda syntax):

```
var result = context.UserRoles
   .Where(ur => ur.UserID == 1 && ur.Role.Name == "Seller")
   .Select(ur => new {ur.RoleID, ur.UserID});
```

Again, projecting out just the two columns into an anonymous class. If you omit the final `Select` statement entirely, you'll get the full `UserRole` entity instance.

Comment: thanks for replying! what if instead of a.UserId ==1 i would like to get the current userid, may i know how do i get it?